# I have some trouble with object in kotlin

Tags: android, object, kotlin

I need to create a variable `vVideo`. This variable is a class type of `SurfaceViewRenderer`. This class 
extends `View` and implements another class who get a function `onFrame`. I need to override this `onFrame`.

Here is what I tried:

```
private var vVideo: SurfaceViewRenderer? = null

    fun startConfigurationAudioVideo() {

        vVideo = object : SurfaceViewRenderer(this) {
            override fun onFrame(frame: VideoFrame?) {
                Log.d("vVideo", "onFrame")
                super.onFrame(frame)
            }
        }

        vVideo = findViewById<SurfaceViewRenderer>(R.id.activity_display_videocast)

...
```

But,
If I do this:

```
vVideo = object : SurfaceViewRenderer(this) {
            override fun onFrame(frame: VideoFrame?) {
                Log.d("vVideo", "onFrame")
                super.onFrame(frame)
            }
        }
```

before this 
`vVideo = findViewById<SurfaceViewRenderer>(R.id.activity_display_videocast)`
I don't have a surfaceRender.
And if I do inverse I don't get the Listener.

The problem is that I don't arrive to declare vVideo with her method onFrame and its surface (its View).
The issue is that I can't have both in the same time.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your issue is not understandable.  Make it more clear

Comment: I edit, I hope it's more understandable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating and instantiating an anonymous class of `SurfaceViewRenderer` and then you are getting the one on your interface, which is a different object.

To make this work, you would have to create a new class that extends `SurfaceViewRenderer` and then use it on your layout.

Something like this:

```
package your.package.name
class SurfaceViewRendererWithFrameListener:SurfaceViewRenderer
{
    override fun onFrame(frame: VideoFrame?)
    {
        Log.d("vVideo", "onFrame")
        super.onFrame(frame)
    }
}
```

Then use it on your layout:

```
<your.package.name.SurfaceViewRendererWithFrameListener
.../>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i got this problem,  `SurfaceViewRenderer` need context in param, so I had `class SurfaceViewRendererWithFrameListener : SurfaceViewRenderer(context) {` 
And I think that, is the reason of an new issu when the activity is create at this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_cast`) :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.production/com.mobizel.activities.VideoCast_Activity.VideoCastActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class`

Comment: Thank you !  all it's  fix now

Comment: @Softon sorry, I just noticed your comment.
Yes, I forgot about the constructor initialisation, but I'm glad you were able to solve your issue.